# How to stop scanner after 6 reading 6 integers?

Tags: java

I am learning Java now and I have a problem. This programm decides whether a third point is inside a rectangle in a Cartesian coordinate system. The first point is the top left corner of the rectangle, the second point is the bottom right corner. You have to input it like this: a b c d e f, where left(a,b) and right(c,d). E and f are the points of the third point. I want the scanner to stop after 6 integers, so without the need to fill in a non-integer, like 'end'. This is a part of my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangle {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    void insideRectangle() {

        int coordinate;
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        int d;
        int e;
        int f;

        System.out.println("Please fill in the numbers (6 maximum), with spaces in between");

        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
        d = 0;
        e = 0;
        f = 0;

        while ( scanner.hasNextInt() ) {
            coordinate = scanner.nextInt();
            a = coordinate;
            coordinate = scanner.nextInt();
            b = coordinate;
            coordinate = scanner.nextInt();
            c = coordinate;
            coordinate = scanner.nextInt();
            d = coordinate;
            coordinate = scanner.nextInt();
            e = coordinate;
            coordinate = scanner.nextInt();
            f = coordinate;
        }

        if ( a > c ) {
          System.out.println("error");
        } else if ( b < d) {
          System.out.println("error");
        } else if ( e >= a && c >= e && f <= b && d <= f ) {
          System.out.println("inside");
        } else {
          System.out.println("outside");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: That `while` loop is reading 6 coordinates on *every* loop pass. Just kill the loop and keep the body. (Also, you can dispense with the duplicate `coordinate` variable and just assign directly to `a..f`, and even those should be refactored, but that's probably for a bit in the future.)

Comment: Just remove the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked. I just started this week ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
int[] values = new int[6];
int i = 0;
while(i < values.length && scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    values[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Then the array contains your 6 values.

Answer (score 0):

I like [@Jean Logeart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/749588/jean-logeart)'s approach, but I would use a `for` loop instead:

```
int[] values = new int[6];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length && scanner.hasNextInt(); ++i) {
    values[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

For the sake of completeness, you can then assign the array values to your `a`, `b`, `c` variables to keep the rest of the code working:

```
int a = values[0];
int b = values[1];
int c = values[2];
int d = values[3];
int e = values[4];
int f = values[5];
```

Note that this will work even if the scanner found less than 6 values, because array values are initialized to 0.

Finally a tip: to test the implementation, you can create a `Scanner` from a string, for example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11");
```